# How can I distinguish これ (this) and それ (that) in practice while learning Japanese?

Tags: word-usage

I would like to learn some tips to distinguish these two words, because I'm having difficulty in understanding them while communicating with individuals; any advice is greatly appreciated. I know that they both end in れ and one begins with そ and the other with こ. Is there any English analogies I can apply to these words, like a mnemonic?

Comment: You've already identified them with English "this" and "that".  What more do you need? Perhaps you can provide contexts in which you find it hard to understand them.

Comment: Do you mean you often forget which is *this* and which is *that*?

Comment: I would think distinguishing それ and あれ is harder for speakers of some languages including English, especially when these words don't refer to concrete objects.

Comment: Sometimes words just have to be memorised.

Comment: If you are native speaker of Spanish language (as your username might suggest), then you can compare 3 series of Japanese demonstrative pronouns with 3 series of [Spanish demonstrative pronouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_pronouns#Demonstrative_pronouns): この, これ = éste/ésta/esto, その, それ = ése/ésa/eso, あの, あれ = aquél/aquélla/aquello. Amongst those Japanese pronouns, those ending with 〜の are used only adjectivally before nouns (e.g. この本 = "this book"), while those ending with 〜れ are used as nouns (e.g. これは本だ = "this is a book").

Comment: There are also some expressions, containing demonstrative pronouns, which have meanings not necessarily guessable from meanings of pronouns. E.g. meaning of これから = literally "from this" → "from now", can be easily guessed from meanings of its components, but それに = "besides, moreover" cannot be guessed, and should be memorized as a whole.

Comment: @Arfrever I also speak spainish your comment is really helpful actually. Like answer wise.

Comment: one other thing in addition to @Arfrever 's comment (upvoted) where compounds can inflect subtleties is that placing だよ after これ/それ/あれ can impart different meanings, roughly "that's the stuff!", "that's what I mean / exactly!", "it's that thing, what's the word?" (other variant meanings occasionally implied in certain contexts)